# How to add/update query string link to end of exisiting URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have existing product filters on my side bar, although I'm trying to have functional links that can update or add to the filters on the products.
[snippet of current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW0W2.jpg)

Currently I have the links with < a href="?filter_caster-type=swivel" > although when using that link it removes the current queries. Is there an easy way to have a link that updates or adds to the current queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
// assumes the URL already contains a query string, better checking will be needed if this isn't always the case
var paramsFromURL = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));

paramsFromURL.set("WhateverYouNeedToAdd", "TheValueYouWant")

// gives something like http://example.com/path/?ExistingThing=foo&WhateverYouNeedToAdd=TheValueYouWant
var updatedURL = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname + "?" + URLSearchParams.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the query into your current URL, you can doing by a javascript function, something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location.replace(window.location.href + $(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

This function take your current URL and append the filter that you have in your `a` tag and then reload.